# How to show a floating message with a help message to the user

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-animation, android-xml

I modified my app, i.e changed the style of the app from an expandable lisview to show it's content to a viewpager with a pagetitlestrip. Now my app is much more cute but uninstalls have increased a lot since my new update has been released.

I'm pretty sure that users are uninstalling my app because they don't know that they must do a swipe movement to the left to see the next content of the app.

So I think that I need to add some help for the users. I thought about a floating imageview of an arrow to the right with a message showing the text "move to right to see more content" and a close button.

Which is the best strategy to achieve this? Whould be to use some xml tricks? or it should be done by java code? Any sample codes whould be great.

This is my xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- The main content view -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
                android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:paddingTop="4dp"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                style="@style/CustomPagerTitleStrip"/>
        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"
        style="@style/NavigationDrawerStyle"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: You can try something like this: https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView

Comment: @Opoo i whould prefeer to add a tiny code to my app instead of a third party library but thanks

Comment: @Opoo I'm trying your proposal but it seems that cannot be used with newer projects which use AppCompatActivity, i'm getting this error: java.lang.RuntimeException: insertShowcaseViewWithType cannot be used when the theme has no ActionBar

Comment: That's a shame. Apparently they aren't maintaining it very well. Maybe a manual solution will work.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
            android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:paddingTop="4dp"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            style="@style/CustomPagerTitleStrip"/>
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
    <RelativeLayout
        visibility="gone"
        ...>
        <ImageView.../>
        <Button.../> -->dismiss
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Depending or whether you already showed it (saved in SharedPreferences or database) you would show it. You have to add the xml of the overlay below the viewpager xml, because the xml is parsed topdown.

Comment: If I do that, the help layout will be below the viewpager and it should be floating in the middle of the screen. BTW see my comments on the question to your third party proposal, I'm trying it but I'm having problems

Comment: It will be on top of the ViewPager , because in a RelativeLayout the lowest layout in your xml will be drawn on top (if you haven't set any relative positioning). If you give your RelativeLayout a transparent background and center your imageview in the relativelayout, it looks like it's floating right?

Comment: I successfully add a floatting showcaseview from your thirdparty propossal but it is putting the "GOT IT" button above the admob banner in the bottom of my app. Do you know if it is possible to change the "GOT IT" possition? I'm using the constructor for SingleShot showcase. There are a lot of constructor with different showcases.

Comment: Not entirely sure, but you could add the ShowCaseView in code and set a topmargin? Maybe this link will provide some coverage for you. https://www.novoda.com/blog/showcaseview-customisation-and-having-consecutive-showcases/